# Boto3 SNS ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sns

I'm getting the following error when trying to call `create_topic()` in Boto3. It works locally in sam running `sam local invoke`, but once deployed, it times out.

`ConnectTimeoutError: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://sns.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"`

Here's the code:

```
 sns = boto3.client('sns')
    topic_name = f'my-sns-topic-{ENVIRONMENT}'
    topic = sns.create_topic(Name=topic_name)
    notification_channel = {"SNSTopicArn": topic["TopicArn"], "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::my-role"}
```

My Lambda function is on private subnets. The function shouldn't require any access to the internet, so I think private subnets are ok (?). All my resources are on the same VPC.

Does the lambda function have to be on a public subnet to reach SNS? I tried adding a `0.0.0.0/0` route mapped to my internet gateway to the route table associated with the private subnet, but that didn't help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My Lambda function is on private subnets. The function shouldn't require any access to the internet,

If your lambda function is deployed in a VPC that does not have internet connectivity, then your lambda function will be unable to reach the service endpoint (`sns.us-east-2`) over the public internet, as you would expect.

If you want private connectivity to the service, then you need to provision a VPC interface endpoint for the service and deploy it in the same VPC as your lambda.